# Dojo widget with template, change template on widget load (add DOM element)

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo, widget

I want to create a dojo widget with a very simple html template:

```
<div id="contentExternal"></div>
```

then on the widget load i want to load certain url from external service. Then after the url is loaded I want to put an  with src argument equal to this loaded url. I have written:

```
dojo.provide("dojoModules.ExternalWebsitePane");
dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
dojo.require("dojoModules.ConfigurationPane");

dojo.declare("dojoModules.ExternalWebsitePane", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated],
    {
        templateString: dojo.cache("dojoModules", "templates/ExternalWebsitePane.html"),
        widgetsInTemplate: false,
        constructor: function() {
        }
        ,
        startup: function() {
            //Get Config
            var serviceParams = new Object();
            serviceParams.ServiceType = "GetConfig";
            ecm.model.Request.invokePluginService("ExternalWebsitePlugin", "ExternalWebsiteService",
                    {requestParams: serviceParams, requestCompleteCallback: function(response) {
                            iframe = new Object();
                            iframe.src = response.configuration.value;
                            iframe.class = "iframe1";
                            var content = document.getElementById('contentExternal');
                            content.appendChild(iframe);
                        }});

        }

    });
```

But the code execution fails on

```
var content = document.getElementById('contentExternal');
content.appendChild(iframe);
```

where it says that content is null. I suspect that the div from html template is not loaded yet. How should i add an element? Or when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when you have templated widgets you should use Dojo attach points. If you have the following template (for example):

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="contentExternalNode"></div>
```

You can then access that node from a property with the same name as your attach point, for example:

```
this.contentExternalNode.appendChild(iframe);
```

I usually do this stuff in the `postCreate` of the widget (I have no clue if it is already available at `startup`).
There is an article about writing your own widget (and more info about templated widgets) [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#templated-widgets).

**Note:** If you use Dojo 1.6 you need to use the `dojoAttachPoint` attribute and NOT the `data-dojo-attach-point`.